# GeoWebCache seed task dies immediately after being submitted

Tags: postgis, geoserver, openstreetmap, geowebcache

The data comes from Geofabrik's Brazil slice: http://download.geofabrik.de/south-america/brazil.html

Imported into a PostGIS DB with osm2pgsql. GeoServer is 2.4.0, running on latest Tomcat 7.0.x, on latest Oracle JVM, on CentOS 64 bits. The GeoServer VM has 1GB RAM and 100 GB disk.

I defined a layer group having planet_osm_line, planet_osm_point, and planet_osm_roads.

I try to seed the cache on this group with the following parameters:

- Grid set: EPSG:900913
- Format: image/png
- Zoom start: 0; Zoom end: 15

When I press Submit, it shows the created tasks, but when I come to the seed page again, there's none. And the CPU isn't being used.

The GCW demo does work and it seems to be feeding the cache. When I use *that,* I can see the heavy usage on `top`.

Another thing: after panning through the map in the demo for a bit, the cache directory is populated with PNGs and has 19 MB. But in the Tile Layers screen, "Disk Used" still shows 0.0B. What's happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see more than 0.0B you must go into GeoWebCache Settings and to set Enable Disk Quota limits.

For a (long time visible) working task you need to go to your layer group in Tile Caching -> Tile layers and to verify the available gridsets.
You must check both (Min/Max) Published zoom levels and Cached zoom levels, to be sure that you don't seed the tiles just for a single/a few zoom level(s).