# Is my Geoserver "Direct WMS Integration" working?

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache

I have activated the "Enable direct WMS Integration" switch in Geoserver 2.5. As far as I can understand, this enables caching of layers without having to use the "gwc/service/wms" endpoint in the WMS URL.

I assume that this enables geowebcache tilecaching dynamically when the tiles are requested. However, I am not seeing the correponding cache being created in the gwc directory in geoserver_data_dir.

Is it working? How can I tell?

Comment: As I can see [here](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/geowebcache/troubleshooting.html), there could be some issues with the generation of tiles

Comment: To enable caching, see this answer, also: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74360/geowebcache-seed-task-dies-immediately-after-being-submitted/76119#76119

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look on this [page](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/geowebcache/using.html) you will see there are a number of conditions that must all be met before caching will occur. So you will need to be certain that **all** of these are met, which in general operation is unlikely.

> When this feature is enabled, GeoServer WMS will cache and retrieve tiles from GeoWebCache (via a GetMap request) only if all of the following criteria are followed:

- WMS Direct integration is enabled (you can set this on the Caching
  defaults page)
- tiled=true is included in the request
- The request only references a single layer
- Caching is enabled for that layer
- The image requested is of the same height and width as the size saved in the layer configuration
- The requested CRS matches one of the available tile layer gridsets
- The image requested lines up with the existing grid bounds
- A parameter is included for which there is a corresponding Parameter Filter

Comment: Thanks....after I added simply the tiled:true parameter to the Openlayers config everything worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to iant, this is how I check if the integration is workin or not.

If you check the HTTP Response Headers on a successful request you would see something like:

```
Cache-Control:max-age=7776000
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Disposition:inline; filename=Cartografia-autostrada.png8
Content-Type:image/png
Date:Thu, 22 May 2014 14:15:34 GMT
ETag:a803579b8cdf87b21bb5481baaf69f40
geowebcache-cache-result:HIT
geowebcache-crs:EPSG:900913
geowebcache-gridset:900913_custom
geowebcache-layer:Cartografia:autostrada
geowebcache-tile-bounds:1281696.0901071709,5841011.9526272025,1286588.059916866,5845903.922436898
geowebcache-tile-index:[6, 2, 3]
Keep-Alive:timeout=15, max=76
Last-Modified:Wed, 07 Aug 2013 11:25:01 GMT
Set-Cookie:GS_FLOW_CONTROL="GS_CFLOW_-2399fb09:1462436e382:-5184"; Version=1
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
ConsoleSearchEmulationRendering
```

while on an unsuccessful one:

```
Cache-Control:max-age=7776000, must-revalidate
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Disposition:inline; filename=Cartografia-autostrada.png
Content-Type:image/png; mode=8bit
Date:Thu, 22 May 2014 14:15:32 GMT
Expires:Wed, 20 Aug 2014 14:15:32 GMT
geowebcache-cache-result:MISS
geowebcache-miss-reason:
Keep-Alive:timeout=15, max=81
Set-Cookie:GS_FLOW_CONTROL="GS_CFLOW_-2399fb09:1462436e382:-5184"; Version=1
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
```

which in "some" cases gives also an explanation for the MISS.

Simone.